# Where to place code for mobile Navbar in materialize css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am trying to create a mobile Nav-Bar using MaterializeCSS, but I do not understand where to post the Javascript.

[The bottom of this page](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#!)

says to put this code:

```
 $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

in my

```
 $( document ).ready(function(){})
```

I have no experience with Javascript at all, so figuring out what this means has been a struggle, even with google-fu.

Does this go within the existing materialize.js file? If so, where?

[here is the code for my navbar](http://pastebin.com/jkeg2L3L)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to create another `scripts.js` file and place it in there. Then reference it at the end of the body tag as a script link like this..

```
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

If that's the only JS code you have you could also include it inline in the HTML like..

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
})
</script>
```

Either way it must follow the `materialize.js` file.

Materialize SideNav: http://codeply.com/go/iwJMN5S52h

Comment: I am still not able to click the icon to display the side navigation panel, I don't know if this has to do with my code or not.

Comment: It still does not work for me. I do not know why, but your answer is technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

After adding this code in the body tag of your html:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Link the `materialize.css` stylesheet and the corresponding `materialize.js` file. Now, since you have a side-nav, all you need to do is create a new js file, link it within your html and add this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
});
```

Make sure to link the scripts after jQuery and `materialize.js`.

Comment: While this does give me the icon when sized down, it does not allow me to click on the icon to reveal my side nav

Comment: I did not know you were trying to do that. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have done this, but it still will not work. I have edited my post to include a  link to my "code" to see if it is incorrect

Comment: Have you tried sizing down your screen? The button should only show at a certain window width. I resized my window to the size of a phone screen and the menu showed up, as well as the side menu.

Comment: Of course, the icon appears but it is not "clickable"